# Struct value storage

Tags: java, c++, clone

I am converting a program originally in C++ over to Java, since I have little experience with C++, and am having some problems.

```
struct indx{ int i,j; };
void increment(indx place) { 

    place.i+=5;
    place.j+=5;

}
```

When C++ passes structures through methods and modifications are made, are they maintained in the rest of the code? In Java terms, will modifying a struct in a method be the same as modifying a clone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing `place` by value which means `increment` is operating on a copy of your structure, not the original. Change to pass-by-reference, like this:

```
void increment(indx& place) {
...
}
```

The function will then be operating on the original structure and any modifications will persist back to the caller.

Comment: what about with vectors, i.e. somevector.push_back(place) ?

Comment: @flyingeagle413 same problem, same solution. Additionally, passing vectors (or any complex data structure) by value is usually the wrong choice because of performance penalties incurred in making a copy. You should usually pass by reference whether you're modifying the structure or not (and if not, mark it as `const` to prevent accidental modification).